# Tortoise SVN Move command fails with message "Unable to lock" 

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

What would cause the "SVN Move versioned files here" command with Tortoise SVN to fail with the error "Unable to lock '', Please execute cleanup command", even after having executed the cleanup command?

Comment: A SVN forum/mailing list is a more appropriate place for this question (which isn't really about programming).

Comment: I disagree - tools related to programming and used by thousands of programmers on a daily basis are very much programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems with the Tortoise move facility too (apart from it being difficult to accomplish with a touchpad) and have switched to using the command line **svn move** command when I need to move something.

**Edit:** Tortoise doesn't come with a command-line client, so I use that from [www.sliksvn.com](http://www.sliksvn.com/).

Comment: What is the easiest way to run the svn command line?  Is that an option through TortoiseSVN? (I thought it was but can't find it, maybe thinking of TortoiseCVS)  No dice on finding anything int he manual.

Comment: There is another at Collab.net: http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/ Download the Command Line client

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before - always in subdirectories of a directory that itself is under source control. If this is the case, please try svn cleanup in the *parent* of the current directory, or in the parent of that as well, etc - i.e., try it in the highest order parent you can find that is under source control.

Comment: Thanks.  No luck with that.  I found the TortoiseSVN mailing list.  Will try there.

Comment: If all else fails, sometimes deleting the Working copy and checking out again helps. There are a few weird problems Subversion can have locally. This is only an option if you don't have local changes, though :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote comments. Johannes, can you make that into an answer?

Comment: That's actually the answer I got on the tortoise mailing list :)

Answer (score 0):

I marked Neil's answer as correct, as this is essentially what led me to a workaround.  The move command actually failed as well, which indicated the problem was not with ToirtoiseSVN, but actually with SVN itself.  I deleted the workspace and re-checked out the repository.  However there were still problems with the folder, so I ultimately had to delete a few folders in the repository itself, and re-commit them before the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the "right click > TortoiseSVN > Repository Browser" then move my directories by dragging and droping them inside the Repository Browser. It worked.

I just had to clean up my directory another time with the "Break locks" option activated in order to update my working copy.